# How to run two web application on wildfly server with different java version?

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly

I want to use Java 8 for one Restful application and Java 11 for another one. I am using one wildfly server in which I want to deployed two Restful applications. The problem is that I want to run one RestFul application on java version 8 and another is on java version 12. 
Is there any setting to set this? 
I am making this application in spring boot.( Latest ) 
I can do this by deploying these applications on different node and on different server of wildfly.
But I want to just use one node and one wildfly server.
Please any one suggest me the different ways for making my thoughts work?

Thanks Pranav

Comment: It is Wildfly itself that is the Java application being run on a VM, so you really need two different Wildfly instances to be able to do this.

Comment: You cannot. The best option is to use 2 different Wildfly servers on a single node. One listening on port 8080 and the second listening on port 8081 by using Wildfly configuration option -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1.

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible, wildfly runs inside the JVM so to can't run a different JVM within the JVM